# Markdown Implementations for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, markdown

What is the best implementation of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for C or C++?

I found these via Google, and would appreciate comments about which ones work well and which ones don't (and which ones I may have missed):

- [peg-markdown](http://github.com/jgm/peg-markdown/tree/master)
- [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/markdown/)
- [Cpp-Markdown](http://cpp-markdown.sourceforge.net/)
- [libsoldout](http://fossil.instinctive.eu/libsoldout/home) (formerly libupskirt)

Comment: see also http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/

Comment: cmark is the fastest

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1. **[peg-markdown](http://hasseg.org/peg-markdown-highlight/)** depends on GLib and other 3rd part tools. I've tested it, it works quite well.

   **Advantages:**

   - Dual-licensed under GPL and MIT.
   - Uses internally formal grammar, so easy to maintain and extend.

   **Disadvantages:**

   - Depends on GLib
   - Provides C API.
2. **[Cpp-Markdown](http://cpp-markdown.sourceforge.net/),** Most C++ code but it is quite slow and little bit bloated. On the other hand it is quite easy to understand and modify, Depends on boost-1.35.

   **Advantages**

   - Depends only on boost
   - Written in C++, looks like less dangerous
   - Licensed under MIT.

   **Disadvantages**

   - Slow (it is still about 10 times faster then Perl implementation, but about 10 times slower than Discount)
3. **[Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/),** This is the code I use for my blog http://art-blog.no-ip.info/cppcms/blog and wiki http://art-blog.no-ip.info/wikipp/en/page/main. It is written by hardcore C programmer and quite hardly mantainable (even the developer activly maintains it).

   **Advantages**

   - Extremely fast
   - Written in pure C (no 3rd part dependencies).
   - Actively maintained
   - Has permissive 3 clause BSD license

   **Disadvantages**

   - Almost impossible to maintain (even I could remove/add some fatures).
   - <strike>Has only FILE API, so I should tweak the code to make it work with general buffer</strike>.
   - <strike>Licensed under 4 clause BSD license that is incompatible with GPL. It is problematic if you want to use it not as part of your GPL-ed software.</strike>

Why do I know them so much?

I'm developing [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net), so I need a good markdown to HTML convertor. When I picked one (Discount), it was the only solution. Since then I've needed to replace it due to licensing issues. That said, I still quite like it because it is the fastest Markdown solution.

P.S.: If you want C++ wrapper for Discount, take a look on http://cppcms.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cppcms/cms/trunk/cxxmarkdown/, It is not the latest version, but it is already tweaked.

**EDIT:** I have just visited Discount site and I had found that it had added a non-FILE API as well. So now it is real library.

**EDIT 2:** If you find better implementation or write your own under FOSS license, let me know ;)

**EDIT 3:** as cloose commented, discount had changed the license to 3 clause BSD.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Discount, but thanks for the good overview of choices.

Comment: Version 2.1.6 of [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) was licensed under 3-clause BSD to make it compatible with GPL.

Comment: Your use of "hardly" here is incorrect.

Comment: Did find https://github.com/vmg/sundown not mentioned here.

Comment: Ah, sundown is not maintained any more, it lives on as https://github.com/hoedown/hoedown.

Comment: What do you mean by "hardly mantainable/impossible to maintain"? That makes it sound like Discount's code is unmaintainable (i.e. a huge mess of spaghetti code that shouldn't be touched with a 10-foot pole). But then you add in parentheses that it's actively maintained and that you could add/remove features without what sounds like too much difficulty. What exactly do you mean by these comments?

Comment: Also, Discount is in the Ubuntu/Debian Repository as libmarkdown2. On these platforms using it is as easy as "sudo apt-get install libmarkdown2", adding the flag -lmarkdown to your compile, and including <mkdio.h>.

Comment: cmark is an another alternative (CommonMark implementation): https://github.com/jgm/cmark

Comment: cmake or the GitHub fork of cmake (https://github.com/github/cmark-gfm) is definitely the fastest.