# Markdown to html objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the simplest implementation of Markdown for a Cocoa application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435288/what-is-the-simplest-implementation-of-markdown-for-a-cocoa-application)

Is there any library written on Objective-c to convert Markdown to HTML?
I need to use Markdown in my iphone app.

Comment: Did you had a look to this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435288/what-is-the-simplest-implementation-of-markdown-for-a-cocoa-application

Answer (score 1):

You should refer  rentzsch's [Markdownlive](https://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive) project.