# Objective-C Parsing Markdown to HTML always truncates last few tags

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xhtml, markdown

I've tried using the solutions presented in:

[What is the simplest implementation of Markdown for a Cocoa application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435288/what-is-the-simplest-implementation-of-markdown-for-a-cocoa-application)

but neither solution return a completely valid html, as the last tag (or two?) are missing. For example:

This markdown:

```
### Markdown Example - Lists

#### Unordered list
* Aenean 
* vel 
    * libero 
    * eget 
* ante

#### Ordered list
1. Aenean 
2. vel 
3. libero 
4. eget 
5. ante
```

Outputs the following html:

```
<h3>Markdown Example - Lists</h3>

<h4>Unordered list</h4>

<ul>
    <li>Aenean </li>
    <li>vel 
        <ul>
            <li>libero </li>
            <li>eget </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ante</li>
</ul>

<h4>Ordered list</h4>

<ol>
    <li>Aenean </li>
    <li>vel </li>
    <li>libero </li>
    <li>eget </li>
    <li>ante
```

(with indentation added for clarity).

The code used to generate this is taken from the second answer (although I tried the first as well, with the same result):

```
    NSString *markdownXHTML = @"";
    if([ext isEqualToString:@"markdown"] || [ext isEqualToString:@"md"]){
        NSString *rawMarkdown = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                             error:NULL];
        const char * prose = [rawMarkdown UTF8String];  
        struct buf *ib, *ob;       

        int length = [rawMarkdown lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] + 1;

        ib = bufnew(length);
        bufgrow(ib, length);
        memcpy(ib->data, prose, length);
        ib->size = length;

        ob = bufnew(64);

        struct sd_callbacks callbacks;
        struct html_renderopt options;
        struct sd_markdown *markdown;


        sdhtml_renderer(&callbacks, &options, 0);
        markdown = sd_markdown_new(0, 16, &callbacks, &options);

        sd_markdown_render(ob, ib->data, ib->size, markdown);
        sd_markdown_free(markdown);


        markdownXHTML = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: ob->data];

        bufrelease(ib);
        bufrelease(ob);
    }
```

Anybody have any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you inadvertently copied the code of the **next** answer from [the question you cite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435288/what-is-the-simplest-implementation-of-markdown-for-a-cocoa-application), which is quite different although it looks similar at first sight. Presumably you are using the wrong function to determine the `length` of your raw data.

Comment: There are two answers, and I tried both. The code that appears above is taken from the second answer. I will clarify in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

Using the MMMarkdown library [1] I was able to fully parse the markdown!

[1] https://github.com/mdiep/MMMarkdown