# Detecting if sentences or numbered list for text parsing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, parsing

I have some text in a file that im trying to parse.

Consider this text file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
1. Line 1
2. Line 2

+ Line 1
+ Line 2
+ Line 3
```

There are three paragraphs in the text file.

First is is a couple of sentences. 
Second one has a sentence **AND** a numbered list.
Third is is a simple bullet list.

My question is, in Objective-C, how can I figure out if the paragraph composition, if its just sentences, I'll return them as NSString, if its a bullet list, I want them separated in an NSArray, if the paragraph is a combination of sentences and numbered list, I'll return them as a dictionary of both NSString and NSArray.

ANy ideas? I know I could use regex to separate them out into arrays or strings, but I don't quite know how to **detect** and verify if the para is an:

1. Paragraph (sentences)
2. Bullet list / Numbered List.
3. Combination of List and Para

I've tried this after reading a bunch of tutorials and SO questions regarding regexpressions.

This expresssion `(?=\d*\s*[\.]?\s*)([a-z\s]+)` does fetch the numbered list, but it also grabs the preceding text before the list. Thats where I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As I write this you have 2 votes to close and no comments or answers, this is not surprising. Folks will be asking: What has he tried? Where is the algorithm? What research has he done? Etc. Etc. What you are asking doesn't fall into the normal area of SO.

Formally what you have is a *language*, which is defined by a *grammar*, and you need to determine whether your data is a *sentence* in this language and if so its constituent parts, called *parsing* and typically involving *lexical* and *syntax analysis*.

Potentially a very large problem, but not always.

The literature on this topic is huge, but as a fairly random starting point take a look at [The Chomsky Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) which very briefly defines some of the above terms.

Now define your grammar. E.g. What is a *sentence*? What is a *numbered sentence*? (Possibly a *number dot* followed by a *sentence*)  What is a *numbered list*? (Possibly one or more *numbered sentence*) Etc.

Is your grammar type 3? If so you can parse it with regular expressions and they are available in Cocoa.

If it isn't type 3 then you'll need to write a *parser* or use a *parser generator*. This ia a large topic but I suspect your grammar will be simple and a simple ad-hoc or recursive descent parser will suffice. (Indeed I'm guessing you can come up with a type 3 grammar if you keep your definitions simple.)

If you get stuck when you get further down the track then you might be able to phrase a question more in the realm SO will help you with.

HTH.

Comment: you are indeed write man

Answer (score 0):

How about using an [Objective-C Markdown parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435288/what-is-the-simplest-implementation-of-markdown-for-a-cocoa-application)?

The grammar is really similar to what you're using, and you won't have to learn to write your own parser.