# Stringing together C and Python code in Go?

Tags: python, c, markdown, go, reddit

[Update](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/msg/db200c677f31852e)

---

I'm trying to create a simple Go function which will simply take in a string of reddit-style Markdown and return the appropriate HTML.

Right now, I know that having [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) installed is a prerequisite and that at least the following three files are used by reddit as wrappers around Discount:

- https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/c/reddit-discount-wrapper.c
- https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/c_markdown.py
- https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/py_markdown.py

Based on this, does anyone know how I can sort of glue all this together with Cgo and [go-python](https://bitbucket.org/binet/go-python/) to create a simple Markdown function? (independent of the rest of the reddit source code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is Markdown, I don't see how Python fits into this. Maybe there's more to it, but if at all possible you should leave Python out of this. If there's a reason to use Python that wasn't in the question, I can edit this answer and address that.

First, try this native Go Markdown package: https://github.com/knieriem/markdown

If that doesn't work, the next easiest thing is to take Discount (or any other Markdown library written in C, such as [GitHub's Upskirt fork](https://github.com/tanoku/upskirt)) and wrap it with cgo or SWIG.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wanted to take reddit's code to be sure that I would be getting exactly the same style of Markdown (they seem to have made various small changes over time), but it looks like such a hassle that it seems useless when there's already a native Go implementation. Alternatively, it doesn't look too difficult to wrap Discount (sans reddit wrapping), which seems to be the fastest implementation around. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889434/markdown-implementations-for-c-c