# Creating markdown files with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, markdown

So I have been making presentations and projects using Rmarkdown and Jupyter Notebooks. This is great because I can breakdown parts as needed and run code a section at a time. Now my projets require cpp, and I have been using Visual Studio 2019, in the new project folder I have been unable to find a way markdown option.
I did find this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889434/markdown-implementations-for-c-c?r=SearchResults&s=1|64.2071](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889434/markdown-implementations-for-c-c?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C64.2071)

However most of these are quite old answers, and those that are still being updated seem to be for Visual Studio CODE not VS2019.

Comment: The linked question talks about C++ libraries for writing markdown, Your IDE (Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code) is irrelevant here.

Comment: VS2019 has an optional markdown extension that's compatible with github's markdown. It recognizes .md files as markdowns. It's pretty well featured.

Comment: @doug is it Markdown Editor by Mads Kristensen?

Comment: Yep, that's the one. I've found it quite useful. You can export html from it too.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.5 now supports markdown editing out of the box, no extensions needed.  I'd post an answer but these is (currently) about VS 2019

Answer (score 2):

Mads Kristensen released a new, "complete rewrite of the original **Markdown Editor** with tons of fixes, tweeks, and performance improvements" (as stated in his Github Repo).
It is the best solution if you work with .MD files within your Visual Studio projects and solutions.
Also, it works with **Visual Studio 2022** too.

Here is the simplest way to find and install it:
Inside your Visual Studio IDE, just go to 
 *Extensions* -> *Manage Extensions* -> *Online* 
 and then type "**markdown editor v2**" at the search box.

Comment: how do we actually create a markdown file? In the Solution Explorer when I go to "add"  I don't see options to just create a file.

Comment: @Hofbr valid question. I'm sure for people who've done this 1000 times, it's super simple. I'm thinking you add a simple text file and save it as .md, but I'm not sure, all tutorials online cover Visual Studio Code

Comment: I confirm that @DumitruDaniel 's method works perfectly. Tested & approved...